# Win10 showing wrong WLAN-symbol in taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I have a laptop that's connected to my WLAN, but Windows 10 is showing the LAN-Symbol in my taskbar:

[image: Taskbar]

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: If you know the solution, please post it as an answer and mark it as accepted. This will make the question easier to find and it will be clearly visible that a solution is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by deleting the icon- and thumbcache. If anyone experiences the same issue: Delete the `IconCache.db` file in the `Local` folder inside of the `AppData` directory. Then start the command-prompt as administrator, kill the `explorer` process with `taskkill -IM explorer.exe -F`, navigate to the `Local` directory in the `Microsoft\Windows\Explorer` folder and delete the cache with `del iconcache*` and `del thumbcache*`. If it won't work, restart the `explorer.exe` and try again. The `IconCache.db` file won't be there though. When you're done just do `shutdown /R /T 0`.

Comment: You have edited your question, not posted an answer. I have rolled back the question to a version before your edit. Full edit history can be seen by clicking the "edited X days ago" link below question.